# Getting SQL Error: 1064 in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is the second time recently that I have gotten the exact same error. I think it has to do with the tutorials I am following having deprecated methods.

Today the error comes from my types_controller.php, line 64:

```
$types = $this->Type->findAll("status=1");
```

Gives me Error:

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'findAll' at
>   line 1

I remember following a tutorial yesterday where a line like $this->Model->search(param) was giving me the error:

> SQL Error: 1064: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'search' at
>   line 1

Not really sure that the issue is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, that method is deprecated. Replace

```
findAll("status=1")
```

with

```
find('all', array('conditions'=>"status=1"))
```

See the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data

Comment: I'd add to always check that you're reading the right manual (see at the top of the page).